# stream analytics and compressed avro

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Hi currenlty were are sending avro message to eventhub. With stream analytics we read from this eventhub. We saw that it is possible to compress our avro in deflate compression. Can Stream analytics read deflated compressed avro

Answer (score 0):

ASA does not support compressed messages for any serialization format as of now,  except for avro. Deflate should work.

Answer (score 0):

ASA natively supports Avro, CSV or raw JSON for input or output sinks.

I personally use this ability to get Avro -> JSON deserialization for "free" without any custom code. You just have to tell ASA the serialization format when configuring the inputs and outputs:
[image]